# A better way to update javascript in Laravel Livewire?

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I recently ran into an issue when building a Laravel Livewire component where the javascript portion wouldn't update when a select input changed. The component is a chart from the Chartist.js library and it displays on load but when I change the select input the chart disappears. I came up with a solution but it feels dirty, anyone have a better solution to this.

line-chart.blade.php

```php
<div class="mt-6">
    <h2 class="text-xl text-gray-600 py-3 font-bold">Location Views</h2>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="flex justify-end px-10 py-6">
            <select wire:model="days" class="block w-40 pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-yellow-500 focus:border-yellow-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md">
                <option value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
                <option value="365">Last 12 Months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="line-chart" class="relative ct-chart">
            <div class="hidden absolute inline-block chartist-tooltip bg-white text-xs shadow text-center px-3 py-1 rounded-md w-36">
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-key"></span><br>
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-date"></span><br>
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-value"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@push('styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.css">
@endpush

@push('scripts')
    <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/chartist.js/latest/chartist.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartist-plugin-tooltips@0.0.17/dist/chartist-plugin-tooltip.min.js"></script>
@endpush

@push('js')
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
            setTimeout(() => {
                Livewire.emit('updateJS')
            })

            Livewire.on('updateJS', function () {
                var data = {
                    labels: @this.labels,

                    // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
                    series: @this.data,
                };

                var options = {
                    height: 300,
                    fullWidth: true,
                    chartPadding: 40,
                    axisX: {
                        offset: 12,
                        showGrid: true,
                        showLabel: true,
                    },
                    axisY: {
                        offset: 0,
                        showGrid: true,
                        showLabel: true,
                        onlyInteger: true,
                    },
                }

                new Chartist.Line('#line-chart', data, options).on("draw", function (data) {
                    if (data.type === "point") {
                        data.element._node.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
                            const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip')

                            tooltip[0].style.top = data.y - 75 + 'px'
                            tooltip[0].style.left = data.x > 200 ? data.x - 150 + 'px' : data.x + 'px'

                            tooltip[0].classList.remove('hidden')

                            const key = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-key')
                            key[0].innerHTML = data.meta[1]

                            const meta = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-date')
                            meta[0].innerHTML = data.meta[0]

                            const value = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-value')
                            value[0].innerHTML = data.value.y === 1 ? data.value.y + ' view' : data.value.y + ' views'
                        })

                        data.element._node.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
                            const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip')
                            tooltip[0].classList.add('hidden')
                        })
                    }
                })
            })
        })
    </script>
@endpush
```

LineChart.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Components;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Carbon\CarbonPeriod;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Livewire\Component;

class LineChart extends Component
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    public Collection $data;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    public array $labels;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public int $days = 30;

    /**
     *
     */
    public function mount()
    {
        $this->data();

        $this->labels = $this->labels();
    }

    /**
     * Trigger mount when days is updated.
     */
    public function updatedDays()
    {
        $this->mount();

        $this->emit('updateJS');
    }

    /**
     * @return Application|Factory|View
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.components.line-chart');
    }

    /**
     * Generates the chart data.
     */
    public function data()
    {
        $locations = request()->user()->locations;

        if ($this->days === 30) {
            $this->data = $locations->map(function ($location) {
                return $this->getDatesForPeriod()->map(function ($date) use ($location) {
                    return [
                        'meta' => [
                            Carbon::parse($date)->format('M j'),
                            $location->name
                        ],
                        'value' => $location->views->filter(function ($view) use ($date) {
                            return $view->viewed_on->toDateString() === $date;
                        })->count()
                    ];
                })->toArray();
            });
        }

        if ($this->days === 365) {
            $this->data = $locations->map(function ($location) {
                return $this->getDatesForPeriod()->map(function ($date) use ($location) {
                    return [
                        'meta' => [
                            Carbon::parse($date)->format('M'),
                            $location->name
                        ],
                        'value' => $location->views->filter(function ($view) use ($date) {
                            return $view->viewed_on->month === Carbon::parse($date)->month;
                        })->count()
                    ];
                })->toArray();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the labels for the chart.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function labels()
    {
        return $this->getDatesForPeriod()->map(function ($date) {
            if ($this->days === 30) {
                return Carbon::parse($date)->format('M j');
            } else {
                return Carbon::parse($date)->format('M');
            }
        })->toArray();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the dates for the specified period.
     *
     * @return Collection
     */
    protected function getDatesForPeriod()
    {
        if ($this->days === 30) {
            return collect(CarbonPeriod::create(now()->subDays($this->days)->toDateString(), now()->toDateString()))
                ->map(function ($date) {
                    return $date->toDateString();
                });
        }

        if ($this->days === 365) {
            return collect(now()->startOfMonth()->subMonths(11)->monthsUntil(now()))
                ->map(function ($date) {
                    return $date->toDateString();
                });
        }
    }
}
```

If I change `document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {}` to `livewire:update` then the chart works as expected when I use the select input, but then the chart doesn't display on load. So to get around this I had to set a timeout and trigger an event that displays the chart on load but will also display the chart on update. I feel like there is a better way to do this, I'm just missing something.

Comment: I suggest you to use AlpineJS. The lib keeps the state alive between the livewire requests, so you would not have to worry about the livewire been already loaded or to set a timeout.

Comment: @itepifanio I'm not sure how I could use AlpineJs to improve this. I'm running a query on the back end based on the information that's passed from the front end. This is outside AlpineJS capabilities.

Comment: Alpinejs communicates well with livewire components using @entangle property. I added a snippet for you.

Comment: Typically with any JavaScript if you see `setTimeout` being used to work around an "issue" it indicates some other challenge with the code/event management etc. that the `setTimeout` helps avoid but is not really a "fix" and might manifest itself as an even harder to debug issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get this to work I removed the `setTimeout()` and the `Livewire.On('updateJS')` and added another event listener inside of `livewire:load` that listens for `livewire:update` and in here we're updating the chart with

```js
chart.update({labels: @this.labels, series: @this.data})
```

Here is the entire code snippet. I feel like this is a much cleaner solution and doesn't feel dirty lol.

```js
<script>
document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
    var data = {
        labels: @this.labels,

        // Our series array that contains series objects or in this case series data arrays
        series: @this.data,
    };

    var options = {
        height: 300,
        fullWidth: true,
        chartPadding: 40,
        axisX: {
            offset: 12,
            showGrid: true,
            showLabel: true,
        },
        axisY: {
            offset: 0,
            showGrid: true,
            showLabel: true,
            onlyInteger: true,
        },
    }

    const chart = new Chartist.Line('#line-chart', data, options).on("draw", function (data) {
       if (data.type === "point") {
           data.element._node.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
               const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip')

               tooltip[0].style.top = data.y - 75 + 'px'
               tooltip[0].style.left = data.x > 200 ? data.x - 150 + 'px' : data.x + 'px'

               tooltip[0].classList.remove('hidden')

               const key = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-key')
               key[0].innerHTML = data.meta[1]

               const meta = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-date')
               meta[0].innerHTML = data.meta[0]

               const value = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip-value')
               value[0].innerHTML = data.value.y === 1 ? data.value.y + ' view' : data.value.y + ' views'
           })

           data.element._node.addEventListener('mouseleave', e => {
               const tooltip = document.getElementsByClassName('chartist-tooltip')
               tooltip[0].classList.add('hidden')
           })
        }
    })

    document.addEventListener('livewire:update', function () {
        chart.update({labels: @this.labels, series: @this.data})
    })
})
</script>
```

Comment: This worked for me on updating fusion charts that were not changing on select change.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the chartist, but I usually use this approach (let me know if the code make sense to you).

```js
<div class="mt-6" x-data="{
    labels: @entangle('labels'), 
    series: @entangle('data'),
    chart: null
}"
x-init="() => {
    const options = {}; // I'll omit part of the code here
    chart = new Chartist.Line('#line-chart', data, options);
},
$watch('series', (dataChart) => {
     // I usually put both, the series data and the labels in an associative array on the livewire component back-end
    const { series, labels } = dataChart;
    chart.update(dataChart);
"
>
    <h2 class="text-xl text-gray-600 py-3 font-bold">Location Views</h2>
    <div class="bg-white rounded-lg shadow overflow-hidden overflow-y-scroll">
        <div class="flex justify-end px-10 py-6">
            <select wire:model="days" class="block w-40 pl-3 pr-10 py-2 text-base border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:ring-yellow-500 focus:border-yellow-500 sm:text-sm rounded-md">
                <option value="30">Last 30 Days</option>
                <option value="365">Last 12 Months</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="line-chart" class="relative ct-chart">
            <div class="hidden absolute inline-block chartist-tooltip bg-white text-xs shadow text-center px-3 py-1 rounded-md w-36">
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-key"></span><br>
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-date"></span><br>
                <span class="chartist-tooltip-value"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think that watching a value from the livewire component it's easier to debug. The use of events to make the communication between back and front-end can make debug challenge when the page gets bigger (and with a lot of events).

With this code your char will be loaded after livewire initial load (you don't need to check the 'livewire:load' event). The chart instance will not be mounted every time you dispatch the updateJS event, only the data will be update.

Ps: I don't know how Chartist works, so I didn't put the code on `chart.update(...)`, but since it's a chart lib it should have an options to update the data. I just want to show you my approach, hope it helps.

Comment: I totally forgot about the @entangle directive. Genius! That being said, now I'm getting the following error `Cannot access 'series' before initialization`. The chart loads fine on initial load, but then when I change the select the data on the chart disappears and I get that error.

Comment: lol wow! So I found the fix without using AlpineJS, I removed the setTimeout and the Livewire.on and added the following `document.addEventListener('livewire:update', function () {
                    chart.update({labels: @this.labels, series: @this.data})
                })`, works like a charm! Although your answer above didn't work for me, it led me to the right answer, so thank you!